# Is Python's time.process_time() including the CPU time spent by child processes? How to include it?

Tags: python, time, cpu-usage

Is Python's time.process_time() including the CPU time spent by child processes?

It is not entirely clear for me from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time).

If not, how can I include it (easily)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time.process_time` doesn't include time spent by child processes. This is pretty clearly stated in the docs:

> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of the sum of the system and user CPU time of the **current process**.

The **current** process, not the current process and all its kids.

I am unaware of any interface for a process to track the process times of its children. The closest I've found is the POSIX `times` function, which provides access to the sum of process times of waited-for child processes, but that's platform-dependent and very limited.

Comment: `man times` doesn't look like it accepts an argument for a PID, instead it reports the "time spent (executing instructions|executing code inside the kernel...) of the calling process".  Is there a way to get this info given a PID?

Answer (score 3):

To add more clarity on the understanding, I wrote a small script that contrasts the difference between process time(CPU time) and clock time.

Also, it shows that the child processes time is not included in the CPU time.

```py
import datetime
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

from numpy import mean


def f(x):
    i = 0
    for j in range(x ** 8):
        i += j
    return i


def process_time():
    clock_t0 = time.time()
    t0 = time.process_time()
    result = f(9)
    print('Result:', result, end='\t')
    t1 = time.process_time()
    clock_t1 = time.time()
    print('CPU time: ', t1 - t0, end='\t')
    print('Clock time: ', clock_t1 - clock_t0)
    return t1 - t0


def multiprocessing_process_time():
    clock_t0 = time.time()
    t0 = time.process_time()
    with Pool(10) as pool:
        result = pool.map(f, [9])
    print('Result:', result[0], end='\t')
    t1 = time.process_time()
    clock_t1 = time.time()
    print('CPU time: ', t1 - t0, end='\t')
    print('Clock time: ', clock_t1 - clock_t0)
    return t1 - t0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Processing in Parent Process\n')
    print('Mean CPU processing time:', mean([process_time() for _ in range(5)]))

    print('\nProcessing in Child Process')
    print('Mean CPU processing time:', mean([multiprocessing_process_time() for _ in range(5)]))
```

Output of the above program:

```sh
Processing in Parent Process

Result: 926510072902560 CPU time:  2.620428 Clock time:  2.6484527587890625
Result: 926510072902560 CPU time:  2.6250959999999997   Clock time:  2.654899835586548
Result: 926510072902560 CPU time:  2.587252000000001    Clock time:  2.6077020168304443
Result: 926510072902560 CPU time:  2.6254989999999996   Clock time:  2.667827844619751
Result: 926510072902560 CPU time:  2.5997120000000002   Clock time:  2.6256277561187744
Mean CPU processing time: 2.6115974

Processing in Child Process
Result: 926510072902560 CPU time:  0.025433999999998846 Clock time:  2.701629877090454
Result: 926510072902560 CPU time:  0.0210480000000004   Clock time:  2.8027760982513428
Result: 926510072902560 CPU time:  0.02214200000000055  Clock time:  2.8002538681030273
Result: 926510072902560 CPU time:  0.02209799999999973  Clock time:  2.7950479984283447
Result: 926510072902560 CPU time:  0.03242999999999974  Clock time:  2.718341112136841
Mean CPU processing time: 0.0246304
```